# What is easiest way to calculate an infix expression using C language?

Tags: c, expression, math, evaluate, infix-notation

Suppose the user inputs an infix expression as a string?
What could be the easiest ( **By easiest I mean the shortes**t) way to evaluate the result of that expression using C language?

Probable ways are converting it to a postfix then by using stacks.But its rather a long process.
Is there any way of using functions such as ***atoi()*** or ***eval()*** that could make the job easier?

Comment: changed case of title - please don't capitalise your titles, Biswajyoti Das

Comment: If you want the shortest, look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/928563/code-golf-evaluating-mathematical-expressions/928804#928804

Comment: That solution doesn't do operator precedence (aka BODMAS) though -- may not be required, but I thought I'd point it out.

Answer (score 6):

C doesn't have an "eval" function built-in, but there are libraries that provide it.

I would highly recommend using [TinyExpr](https://codeplea.com/tinyexpr). It's free and open-source C code that implements math evaluation from a string. TinyExpr is only 1 C file, and it's about 500 lines of code. I don't think you'll find a shorter or easier way that is actually complete (and not just a toy example).

Here is a complete example of using it, which should demostrate how easy it is:

```
#include "tinyexpr.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("%f\n", te_interp("5 * 5", 0)); //Prints 25
    return 0;
}
```

If you want to build an expression solver yourself, I would recommend looking at the [TinyExpr source-code](https://github.com/codeplea/tinyexpr) as a starting point. It's pretty clean and easy to follow.

Answer (score 5):

Certainly the most instructive way (and possibly even the easiest, once you know how) is to learn how to write your own [recursive descent parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser). A parser for infix expressions in C isn't very long.

[Here's one](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/03/14/some-problems-of-recursive-descent-parsers/) of a number of excellent blog posts by Eli Bendersky on parsing. (This one is the one that's most relevant to you, but I highly recommend all of them.) It contains source code for an infix expression parser -- admittedly in Python, not C, but the conversion should be fairly straightforward, and you'll learn a lot in the process.

Answer (score 2):

you need to parse the string.  there's no `eval()` in C (as in most static languages), so you need to either write your own parser or find some library to help.

since most easy to use parsers are for C++ and not C, i'd rather use a full embeddable language.  my absolute favorite is [Lua](http://lua.org), which can be incredibly lightweight if you don't include the libraries.  also, the syntax is nicer than C's, so your users might like it better.

of course, Lua is a full-blown programming language, so it might not be appropriate, or maybe it could help in other ways (to make it easier to extend your application).

Comment: Here is a code fragment from my answer to a similar question that implements expression evaluation with Lua: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156572/evaluating-mathematical-expressions-using-lua/1157717#1157717

Comment: If all you're doing is evaluating math expressions, Lua is not "lightweight"! Use a library made just for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

One clean (possible not short) way to do it is to build a tree, like a compiler would.

For example, say you have the expression "2+3". The '+' would be the head. The '2' would be the left child and the '3' would be the right child.

Since each expression evaluates to a value, this tree can be extended for infinitely complex expressions: it just needs to be sorted in order of precedence for each operator. Low precedence operators (like '+' go at the top, while high-precedence operators (like '*') go at the bottom. You would then evaluate the expressions on the tree from the bottom up.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build in interpreter of some scripting language.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the string into an array of tokens which are the operands and operators.
Convert the infix token array to a Reverse Polish Notation array.
After the equation is in RPN, then you can pop tokens off the stack and operate on them.

Take a look at the Wikipedia article on [Reverse Polish Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation).  It shows how to do the conversion and the calculation.