# implementation of the calculus functions i.e f(x), in programming

Tags: function, math, calculus

I want to write a program that calculates a given math function (by the user) with specific set of values.

The user is asked to type a function, say he typed **f(x)= (x^2)+3x+1** then through the program I should show the outputs of [ f(3), f(6) and f(9) ] .

The question specifically is how to fetch these x's in the typed function, then how to convert the function from a string to a double or float.

Do you have any thoughts about that ?

suppose that I'm using C , or C++

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151127/evaluating-mathematical-expressions and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115872/what-is-the-best-way-to-evaluate-mathematical-expression-in-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an easy task, especially as operators hold precedence over others.

Have a look at some of these links so see what you're dealing with:

[Equation (expression) parser with precedence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28256/equation-expression-parser-with-precedence)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator-precedence_parser

Comment: loool, I just realized how hard the task. I really feel like a stupid teenager :D . thx dude.

Comment: Not a bad long-term project, though, if you're willing to put some sort of commitment to it.